# Why is the user-agent style sheet overriding my css

Tags: xpages

[See solution below]

I am unable to control the styling of buttons in an Xpage application in which I am extending the Bootstrap theme.

I want a transparent button. What I get is this.

[image]

Examining in Chrome Dev tools reveals

[image: Examining in Chrome Dev tools reveals]

that for some reason the class "btn btn-default" has been added to the class. But the real problem surfaces when I try to track down where the grey is coming from:

[image]

the user agent???

What is going on????

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:button
        value="Example"
        id="btn"
        styleClass="btn btn-secondary">
    </xp:button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Example</button>
</xp:view>
```

SOLUTION:

All the answers were good and helped me come up with the final solution.

First, I did use the disableTheme property to prevent Xpages from automatically adding the btn btn-default class.

I didn't know that secondary was bootstrap 4 only. I am using 3 as Knut surmised, and I don't want to venture on to 4 yet.

Here is the css for my button:

```
.btn.btn-bryan {padding: 0px; margin: 0px;color: #3379b7;background-color: transparent;text-align: left;}
```

the button code:

```
<xp:button
    value="#{entry2.mnuItmNme}"
    id="button2"
    type="button"
    styleClass="btn btn-bryan btn-block"
    disableTheme="true">
     <xp:span
       style="margin-right:10px;color:#337ab7"
       styleClass="glyphicon glyphicon-#{entry2.mnuIcon}">
     </xp:span>
     <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="dynamicCustomControl"
        onComplete="XSP.partialRefreshGet('#       {id:dynamicCustomControl}')">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var x = entry2.mnuItmTrg;
        viewScope.controlName = x;
        getComponent('dynamicCustomControl').show(null)}]]>               </xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 theme uses "concat" mode to set styleClass in  XPages controlls. You can see it belowe.

```
<!-- XPages Buttons -->
    <control>
        <name>Button</name>
        <property mode="concat">
            <name>styleClass</name>
            <value>btn btn-default</value>
        </property>
    </control>
```

It means that it will always add *btn btn-default* to styleClass property of Button. To resolve this you can create your own ThemeId and set it in you Buttons.

```
   <control>
        <name>Button1</name>
        <property mode="override">
            <name>styleClass</name>
            <value>myButton</value>
        </property>
    </control>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you set the css classes yourself using the styleClass parameter, maybe if you prevent the theme to add classes to your button by adding disableTheme="true" to your button might help.

Answer (score 2):

Class `btn-secondary` is not available in Bootstrap 3.

You probably extend theme "Bootstrap3" or "Bootstrap3_flat".
Switch to theme "**Bootstrap4**" instead and it will work:

[image]